# Flush cout manually only

Tags: c++, stream, cout, flush

As far as I know streaming `std::endl` into `std::cout` will flush it. I get that that behavior makes sense for most applications.

My problem is that I have some output that uses multiple `std::endl`'s and therefore flushes the output. This is really bad for the performance of my program and also causes a lot of graphical glitches since I am jumping around quite a lot.

So my question is if I can tell `std::cout` to wait with the next flush until I explicitly call `std::cout.flush()` or stream `std::flush` into `std::cout`.
If this is possible I'd also like to know how I then can reverse that since it does not always make sense for me.

Comment: `std::endl` is an explicit call to `std::ostream::flush` followed by writing a newline. If you don't want `std::endl` to flush, don't use `std::endl`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 *"`std::endl` is an explicit call to `std::ostream::flush` followed by writing a newline"* - quite the reverse... newline *then* flush.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `std::cout << '\n'` instead of `std::endl`. This avoids the flush after every line. `std::endl` will always flush, since that is its purpose. There's no option to disable that behavior. However, there's no requirement to use `std::endl` at all. Ultimately, you can't avoid all flushing as the buffer for `std::cout` is finite, so eventually, the output will be flushed regardless if you use `std::endl` or `'\n'`.

If you want to increase the buffer size for standard output, you could try [increase buffer for cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202147/increase-buffer-for-cout).

Comment: This works to an extent, but `cout` is buffered and will still flush on its own eventually when the buffer fills.

Comment: The OP is just trying to reduce flushing to improve performance, he doesn't need to eliminate it entirely.

Comment: Obviously, you have to flush if the buffer fills. There's no way to avoid that.

Comment: You can provide a larger buffer with [.pubsetbuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/pubsetbuf/) as well.

Comment: An overengineered solution might redirect cout to a stringstream first, and then when OP wants to flush, undo the redirect (restoring the original streambuf) and then pump the contents of the stream to cout, then redirect again.

Comment: @Barmar: Ultimately I think you're right, however OP explicitly asked for nothing to be written to cout until they explicitly want it to be.

Comment: @AndyG that would still cause multiple flushes if the stringstream were larger than the buffer size.

Comment: I see. I wasn't aware `std::endl` included a call of `std::flush`. That helped a lot. I will also keep in mind that I might actually need to increase the buffer size of `std::cout`.

Comment: @AndyG It's an XY problem. He explained his goal, which is just to avoid flushing after every line. He didn't really need to disable all flushing, that was just his mistaken assumption.

Comment: @Barmar: Agreed. That solves OP's problem. I suppose I'm attempting to solve the problem of the next person who Googles "How to never flush cout until I tell it to." Regarding multiple flushes in the stringstream solution I posted, I don't think that's a problem. Conceptually I would think of all of them as a single flush.

Comment: @b4hand then how come I seen output on screen even I don't use `std::endl` which  flushes  buffer.

Comment: @AbhishekMane: I'm not sure in what context your question is about. It may be better to post a new question referencing this question, but some streams are unbuffered like `std::cerr` so all output is immediately flushed. Other streams are buffered like `std:cout`, so as long as you are outputting a string longer than the buffer, you'll see it flushed regularly enough.

Comment: @b4hand std::cout<<"a"; this is also prints on screen directly not wait for manually flush the buffer even the it is single char.

Comment: That behavior is implementation dependent and not reliable. `std::cout` is not required to be unbuffered, and in fact, in many real world environments it is not unbuffered, so you shouldn't rely on that behavior or your program will break when you move it to a different environment.