# How to flush buffer manually?

Tags: c++, buffer, flags, flush, manipulators

[this is same Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30314985/11862989) but not answered properly.

**Code**

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    char ch='a';
    std::cout<<ch;
}
```

**Output**

```
a
```

so here only one character in output stream which leads to buffer. so buffer is  not full still it shows ouput on screen. Means buffer is flushed automatically.

so please give example where buffer not flushes automatically and we have to use the manipulator flag `flush`.

Comment: What makes you think this is flushing? The remaining buffer is simply printed at the end of the program

Comment: @AlanBirtles but if I include `getch()` as last statement of the program. still before that executes it print output as `a` .

Comment: If you start an input operation the output is deliberately flushed

Comment: @AlanBirtles ohh. but  how can I see that buffer is not flushed way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see whether your stream is buffered by sleeping between outputs, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        char ch = 'a';
        std::cout << ch << "\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    }
}
```

On some platforms you might need to enable buffering on `stdout` by calling [`setvbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf):

```
std::setvbuf(stdout, nullptr, _IOFBF, BUFSIZ);
```

Comment: I checked your code but it stopping screen for 500 sec after `a` printed. first `a` prints at moment after code runs.

Comment: have you called `setvbuf`?

Comment: yeah it's working. Thanks. can you explain `setvbuf` exactly doing here or any article which explains it.  I checked it on cppreference but  I can't understand.

Comment: it enables buffering

Comment: so on some platforms buffering not happen we have to enable it. means `std::cout<<ch` it not wait for buffer to be full just prints it on screen, right ?