# What is a good alternative to VS 2010 for creating C++ programs?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am just starting out learning to program C++. Visual Studio is nice but its so picky and its caused a lot of problems for me getting my code to compile. So I heard code blocks is a good one. Does anyone know of any others that are simple and hassle free?  I tried to create a hello world program in VS 2010 with the instructions in my book and of course it went crazy and said you can't do this that and the other. =/

Comment: C++ is C++. If your code doesn't compile on one compiler, it probably won't compile on another either. (And if it does, your code is likely broken.) VS is pretty much as simple as it gets...

Comment: Possibly, your book is too old to teach you modern C++.

Comment: Already answered this. See the bottom portion of [my answer to your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8872113/366904). Switching to a different compiler because Visual Studio is picky isn't going to do you any good at all. Only switch if you don't like Visual Studio and prefer something else. Nothing is going to be simpler or easier to write code. C++ is a hard language.

Comment: What book are you using?  If your book actually had the exact code that you posted in your previous question, then you need [a new book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 5):

You are going to have to learn, sooner hopefully, than later.. C++ requires you to be very specific in writing your code, and it doesn't matter which version you use.  C++ is a standard language, and all compilers more or less conform to the same specification.

If your code isn't compiling, it's because you're doing something wrong when you are writing it.  Give some examples, and we may be able to help.  A new compiler won't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is language specific. There's no (good) programming language that allows you to type your code loosely.
Nevertheless, take a look at [my answer on another question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368649/how-to-get-started-learning-mingw-c/8368720#8368720)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for lighter IDEs then you may take a look at [this](http://beans.seartipy.com/2006/12/31/six-popular-ides-for-developing-software-in-cc-on-windows-platform/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by picky – if you don't mean the compiler but the IDE (that it gets to much in your way in the writing process) I suggest you try it with a general-purpose text editor and standalone compiler instead. I like kate best, when forced to use Windows I take Notepad++. As the compiler you could e.g. continue using Visual, go for gcc (MinGW on Windows), or the Intel C++ compiler.

All that is IMO much easier on a Linux, so my recommendation would be [K/X]Ubuntu + kate + gcc. (You can still easily port the programs to Windows, much easier than it is the other way around.)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Notepad++  a free source code editor which supports several programming languages running under the MS Windows environment and MinGW (windows port of gcc).